# Missing nested class when serializing object to JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to serialize some classes into JSON using Unity's `JsonUtility.ToJson()` method. Here are the classes I am serializing:

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveData
{
    public int maxHealth;
    public int HealthRegenSpeed;
    public int maxMana;
    public int ManaRegen;
    public int level;
    public int RequireExp;
    public int currentExp;
    public List<PlayerQuest> QuestList2;
    public Inventory Inventory;
}
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public ItemDatabaseObject database;
    [SerializeField] private List<InventorySlot> Container = new List<InventorySlot>();
}
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySlot
{
    public int ID = -1;
    public ItemObject item;
    public int amount;
}
```

And this is the function where I'm doing the serialization:

```
public void Save()
{
    target = GetComponent<PlayerProperties>();
    SaveData saveobject = new SaveData();
    saveobject.QuestList2 = target.QuestList2.Select(q => new PlayerQuest
    {
        QuestID = q.QuestID,        
        IsDone = q.IsDone,
        CurrentStep = q.GetCurrentStep()
    }).ToList();
    saveobject.maxHealth = target.GetMaxHealth();
    saveobject.HealthRegenSpeed = target.GetHealthRegenSpeed();
    saveobject.maxMana = target.GetMaxMana();
    saveobject.level = target.level;
    saveobject.currentExp = target.CurrentExp;
    saveobject.RequireExp = target.RequireExp;
    saveobject.ManaRegen = target.GetManaRegenSpeed();

    saveobject.Inventory = GetComponent<Inventory>();
    string json2 = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveobject);
    print("saveobject.Inventory " + JsonUtility.ToJson(saveobject.Inventory));
    string localpath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.json";
    File.WriteAllText(localpath, json2);
}
```

I was expecting the resulting JSON to have a structure similar to this:

```
{
  "maxHealth": 50,
  "HealthRegenSpeed": 1,
  "maxMana": 50,
  "ManaRegen": 3,
  "level": 1,
  "RequireExp": 50,
  "currentExp": 0,
  "QuestList2": [],
  "Inventory": {
    "database": {
      "instanceID": 34422
    },
    "Container": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "item": {
          "instanceID": 34180
        },
        "amount": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But instead I'm getting the following JSON:

```
{
  "maxHealth": 50,
  "HealthRegenSpeed": 1,
  "maxMana": 50,
  "ManaRegen": 3,
  "level": 1,
  "RequireExp": 50,
  "currentExp": 0,
  "QuestList2": [],
  "Inventory": {
    "instanceID": -384204
  }
}
```

As you can see, the serialization of the `Inventory` class is incorrect, and it's missing all the details about the items in the inventory. However, when I run `JsonUtility.ToJson(saveobject.Inventory)`, it returns the expected JSON(Inventory class only not the SaveData class ).

```
{
  "database": {
    "instanceID": 34422
  },
  "Container": [
    {
      "ID": 0,
      "item": {
        "instanceID": 34176
      },
      "amount": 1
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "item": {
        "instanceID": 34180
      },
      "amount": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong in my implementation?

Here is a diagram of the components for reference:

[image: Player Components]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a plain C# without inheritance from MonoBehaviour that has the same attributes as Inventory class

```
public class PlayerSaveInventory
{
public ItemDatabaseObject database;
public List<InventorySlot> Container = new List<InventorySlot>();
//contructor
public PlayerSaveInventory(ItemDatabaseObject dt, List<InventorySlot> ct)
{
    database = dt;
    Container = ct;
}
 
}
```

then use contructor to pass value to it:

```
saveobject.Inventory = new PlayerSaveInventory(GetComponent<Inventory>().database, GetComponent<Inventory>().GetInventorySlot());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Unity's [Documentation of SerializeReference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html), it mentions that the default behavior of serializing `UnityEngine.Object` fields (including through json serialization), is **by reference** rather than by value.

So when you see `"instanceID": -384204` reference serialization is occurring due to Inventory being a child or instance of `Monobehaviour` which IIRC is a child of `UnityEngine.Object`.

If possible, change it to another form of serialized object that is not a child of `UnityEngine.Object`.